# How do I retrieve every row that is at least `interval` apart with Django's ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Suppose I have the following model:

```py
class MyModel(Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...
```

I'd like to retrieve every row for `MyModel` that is at least some interval (in seconds) from the previous row. Rows are typically added every 30s, but I'd like to get those that are 30s or more apart.

I've tried a variety of different solutions with the following getting me the closest.

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    time_diff=F("timestamp") - Window(
        expression=Lag("timestamp"),
        order_by=(F("timestamp"),)
    )
)
```

Obviously, it doesn't really do anything, but, unlike below, this doesn't immediately error out. The field `time_diff` exists when I try to use it (i.e. `queryset.last().time_diff` outputs a `timedelta`). However, when I try to `.filter` on `time_diff`, I get an error like `NotSupportError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause`.

Some of the other, non-working, attempts I've tried are below (note that I'm also trying to limit the records to a specific date range, but that's working fine):

```py
start_date = datetime(...)
end_date = datetime(...)
time_interval = ...  # total seconds

time_diff_window = Window(
    expression=Lag('timestamp'),
    order_by=F('timestamp').asc(),
)

queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(
    timestamp__range=(start_date, end_date),
).annotate(
    time_diff=Extract('timestamp', 'epoch') - Extract('lagged_timestamp', 'epoch'),
    lagged_timestamp=Lag('timestamp', default=start_date, over=time_diff_window),
).filter(
    time_diff__gte=time_interval,
).order_by('timestamp')
```

```py
window = Window(expression=Lag("timestamp"), order_by=F('timestamp').asc())
lagged_timestamp = Lag("timestamp", default=Value(timedelta(seconds=0), output_field=DurationField()), over=window,)

# Compute the time difference between the current row and the previous
time_diff = Coalesce(F("timestamp") - lagged_timestamp, Value(timedelta(seconds=0), output_field=DurationField()))

# Filter the rows where the time differences is greater than the requested interval
readings = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    time_diff=time_diff,
).filter(
    time_diff__gte=timedelta(seconds=time_interval),
    timestamp__range=(start_date, end_date),
).order_by("timestamp")
```

I know it's possible to do this in Python, but I'd really like to try and get this working through the ORM and let the DB do the heavy lifting.